# Domain and Co-Domain of an Inverse Function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Say we have a function $f : A \rightarrow B$,

Is it right to say that $f^{-1} : B \rightarrow A$?

I'm not really sure how the inverse function relates to the function in terms of domain and co-domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function is bijective, then yes, the inverse will switch the domain and codomain around compared to the original function.

If the function is injective but not surjective (one-to-one but not onto), then you need to restrict $B$ to the smaller set $f(A)$, the image of $f$. For instance, if you have the function $f:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ given by multiplication by $2$, what will the inverse function do to any odd number? It can't do anything at all. So the inverse function can only have the *even* numbers as domain.

Finally, if $f$ is not injective, then the best you can do is to shrink $A$ to a smaller set so that $f$ becomes injective again, but unlike in the above paragraph, there is no canonical, preferred way of doing that.

Comment: This makes sense and helps a lot with the problem I was given. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the function is one-to-one and onto or not.

For example $$ f: \mathbb {R^{\ge 0}}\to \mathbb {R} $$ defined by $$f(x)=x^2$$ is not onto so you can not say that its inverse $$ f^{-1}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^{\ge 0}}$$ does exist.

We need to restrict the co-domain of $f$ to the image of $f$ and have $$ f^{-1}:\mathbb{R^{\ge 0}}\to \mathbb {R^{\ge 0}}$$ as $$f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt {x}$$

Comment: That's not really the inverse function, though. At least not yet. Note that, for instance, $f(-5) = 25$, but $f^{-1}(25) = 5\neq -5$, which goes against what the inverse is supposed to do. You need to also restrict the _domain_ of $f$, as the function isn't injective. The conventional way is to restrict that too to the non-negative reals, but one may just as well choose to go wth the non-positive reals if one so desires. Or a mix of the two, to get something fancy and exotic and mostly useless.

Answer (score 0):

Not always.

First of all $f$ must be injective for $f^{-1}$ to exist.

In general $f^{-1}$ is only defined on $f(A) \subset B$, that is  $f^{-1} : f(A) \to A$.

If $f$ is onto, then $f(A) = B$ and you indeed have $f^{-1} : B\to A$. In this case, $f$ is both injective and onto, hence it is bijective.

Answer (score 0):

Reference : Seymour Lipschutz, Schaum's Outline Of Set Theory ( at : archive.org)

---

- In general, the exponent  *-1* applied to a relation R so, "R exponent-1" is the *inverse relation* of the relation R.

Any relation has an inverse ( consisting in the inversed ordered pairs of the original relation).

Example. Let R = { ( 3,4) , (3,9) }. The inverse relation of R is { (4,3), (9,3)}.

- Since a function is a relation, any function has an inverse, which is the *inverse relation of this function.*

But, ***it's not true always true that the inverse relation of a function is also a function.***

Let f be a function : from { 1,2} to {5,6} such that f(1) = f(2)=5.

So f = { (1,5), (2,5) }

The inverse relation of f is { (5,1), (5,2) }. This relation is not a function, since it has 2 ordered pairs with the same 1st element , but a different second element.

- What are the *necessary conditions* under which the inverse relation of a function from A to B is automatically a function from B to A.

(1) since it has to be a function from B to A, it is required that any element of B to be relatied to some element of A, which means that the range of the original function from A to B is equal to B;  that is, it is required the original function to be ***onto B.***

(2) since it is a function from B to A, it is required no element of B to be related to more than one element of A, which means that no 2 different elements of A are related to the same element of B in the original function; this implies that the original function is ***one-one.***

So: *the inverse relation of a function f from A to B is automatically a function from B to A iff the original function f is 1-1 and onto.*

In case the inverse relation of a function is also a function, we can call it the *inverse function* of the original one.